# How to export all user stories from openproject (to be imported in jira)?

Tags: jira, data-migration, openproject

Currently, we are using openproject as Scrum backlogs and want to migrate to Jira.

The migration is planed with the following steps:

1. export all tickets (user stories, epics, etc.) as CSV
2. if needed, manually edit the CSV file prior to the import
3. import the CSV file in Jira

The first point is described [here](https://docs.openproject.org/user-guide/work-packages/exporting/). The only problem here is the limit of 500 items.

> Note: If you need to export more than 500 items, filter the work packages appropriately to export multiple files.

Is there an automatic way to export to multiple files? Or better, can this limit be changed to export all items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By filtering the work packages, you can export the items "by chuncs".

One way is to select the desired work packages (i.e. Versions) in the Filter view. Just add more versions (Ctrl + Click) until the number is close to 500 but still below.

"Save as..." can be used to store the filter in case you need to reexport everything.

Then do the same with the remaining versions until everything is exported. The resulting files can easily be merged.

To ensure that all items are indeed exported, compare the sum of the exported items and the total items. If it is a match, you are done. Otherwise, you need to find the missing versions.

A side note: attachments cannot be exported that way. Relations between items are limited to child->parent.